# Integer multiplied by 10 to float

Tags: floating-point, integer, arduino

I have an integer which is the temperature with one decimal, multiplied by 10. For example: the integer of 235 should become a float of 23.5. How do I put this into a float?

I know I can get the number before the decimal point by doing int/10 and the decimal by int%10. Could I combine these two values into one floating point number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overthinking it a little. By casting an int to a float, and dividing it by 10, the decimal will be preserved:

```
float degrees;
int degreesTimesTen;

degreesTimesTen = 235;
degrees = (float)degreesTimesTen/10;

// degrees is equal to 23.5
```

Comment: Or just divide by 10.0.

Comment: Right. By default the language is going to see an int divided by an int and do the math as integer so 235 / 10 = 23. However, changing either parameter to float makes it a float divide. Both "(float)value / 10" or "value / 10.0" give 23.5 if value is 235.